# Creating a New Dict from a Nested Dictionary filtering only one dimension of the tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I need to designa  function that takes a dict, for instance: {(Name, Occupation,Age):Telephone}, and creates a new_dict filtering only the key-value pairs in which one of the elements on the tuple, for instance "Name", are contained within a reference list, for instance ['John','James','Jameson'].

Right now i have managed to do this using the following code. I´m not very satisfied with the efficient of this code, is there any clever way to accomplish this?

Thanks

```py
def filter_dic(dict,dim,elements):

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict,orient='index')      
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
    filtered_df = pd.concat([df.xs(e,level=dim,drop_level=False) for e in elements])
    new_dict=filtered_df.to_dict()

    return new_dict
```

EDIT: Sharing a simple example data of a dict containing some road distance values between pair o cities:

```
raw_dict={('Bahia','Alagoas'): 583.000000,
          ('Bahia','Bahia'): 187.870070,
          ('Bahia','Ceara'): 1241.000000,
          ('Bahia','DistritoFederal'):1450.000000,
          ('Bahia','EspiritoSanto'):1167.000000}
```

if i ran:

```
filter_dict(raw_dict,dim=1,elements=['Ceara','EspiritoSanto'])
```

I would expect to get a filtered dict:

```
filtered_dict={('Bahia','Ceara'): 1241.000000,
          ('Bahia','EspiritoSanto'):1167.000000}
```

Comment: Do u mind sharing some rows from the data, so one can play with it and test

Comment: Done, shared a simple distance matrix dict that we should filtered only some desidered destinations. Thanks.

Comment: the tuples are just two? or can they be multiple? three? more? Also curious as to why you went the pandas route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def filter_dic(dictionary, elements):
    filtered_dict = {key:value for key,value in dictionary.items()
                     for unit in key
                     if unit in elements
                     }
    return filtered_dict

filter_dic(raw_dict,elements)

{('Bahia', 'Ceara'): 1241.0, ('Bahia', 'EspiritoSanto'): 1167.0}
```

Let me know if this fits your use case. 
 The function does a dictionary comprehension on the keys and checks if any member of the key can be found in the elements list.

Comment: Yes, it helped, thanks. I´ve made some adjustment for it to seacrh for a specific position (argument dim) within n_dimesion tuples:
`def filter_dic(dictionary, dim, elements):
    filtered_dict = {key:value for key,value in dictionary.items()
                     if key[dim] in elements
                     }
    return filtered_dict`